# Smoke/Liquid Ignoring collision object during simulation

Tags: modeling, physics, smoke-simulation, collision

I’m fairly new to Blender and modeling in general, and I’m running into trouble with running simulations (smoke, fire, liquid, etc). I’m trying to produce simulations to be used in a projection mapping project.

I’ve set up a smoke domain around a model I’ve made from an architectural drawing of a wall. The goal is to place emitters in the wall, and have the wall contain the smoke. I’ve set the wall to be a collision object, however, the smoke seems to ignore the wall entirely, filling up the entire domain containing the wall. This problem also occurs when I attempt a fluid simulation as well.

I’m coming up blank with explanations for this, and wondering if I have produce the actual model itself in an incompatible way. I am able to set up working simulations with basic spheres/etc with the same methods. Am I missing something? File below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g60loplq7jp4pe8/board-smoke-test.blend?dl=0

[image: Screenshot from Blender]

Comment: Did You try to make the wall a DOMAIN? On the other hand when the collision object has to keep something INSIDE the operation of FLIP NORMALS is necessary for Blender to know the inside part it crucial - try it. But for sure try to make the wall a domain 1st.

Comment: Any progress with changed domain?

Comment: It seems the domain wasn’t the issue. We’ve resolved it somewhat and I’m about to write up an answer regarding the problem. Our model had n-gons that seemed to be messing up the simulation

Comment: OK, I just tried to use your file and make the wall a domain and everything looks to work well but maybe it was not the desired result for You.